# How to check if EE member has a website address (field carries http:// so it always returns true )

Tags: conditionals, member-details, ifelse

I have the following code:

```
{if url}
    <p><strong>Website</strong><br /> <a target="_blank" href="{url}">{company_name}</a></p>
    <hr />
{/if}
```

However,because the website field in EE's member profile always has "http://" inserted by default, the above code will always return true and display the conditional HTML. I am having to edit profile, remove the "http://" bit and save. Even then the "http" bit is inserted back in again but the code above will work!

Any ideas on how to get around this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

For a solution for now, how about a different conditional?

```
{if "{url}" != "http://"}
    <p><strong>Website</strong><br /> <a target="_blank" href="{url}">{company_name}</a></p>
    <hr />
{/if}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not entering any value within the URL then nothing will not be saved into database for member URL even if URL text box is showing "http://".

The URL text box always shows "http://" to help the user to enter correct URL format with "http://".

So the condition `{if url}` will return false if URL is not entered during registration or edit profile.

Please share if I need to describe more.